# Creating a Pandas DataFrame with a single vector column from a 2-d numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy 2D-array:

```
arr = [
  [10, 20],
  [30, 40]
]
```

Converting it into a pandas dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(arr)` gives me:

```
    0  1
0  10 20
1  30 40
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
          0
0  [10, 20]
1  [30, 40]
```

I can achieve it using

```
df.agg(lambda x: np.array(x), axis="columns")
```

or

```
df.agg(lambda x: [y for y in x], axis="columns")
```

But is there a better way to end up with the single column dataframe in the first place?

Comment: `df.agg` gives you a series, no?

Comment: Don't ask side-questions. Instead, if you really want to know, ask a new SO question. Questions here can actually get closed for "Needs more focus: This question includes multiple questions in one. ..." ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it to a `list` first, then a `Series` first, and finally a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(arr.tolist()))
```

Or, as [@QuangHoang suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70428503/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-single-vector-column-from-a-2-d-numpy-array/70428515?noredirect=1#comment124496347_70428515):

```
df = pd.Series(arr.tolist()).to_frame()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          0
0  [10, 20]
1  [30, 40]
```

Comment: Maybe `pd.Series(arr).to_frame()` as well.